# Set cancel option on a grid that has already been initialized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

Is there a way to set the **cancel** option on a grid that has already been initialized?   I'm using the serverside MVC wrapper and have this,

```
.Events(events => events.Cancel("function() {alert('hi');}"))

Clientside I tried:  
$("#grdTest").kendoGrid({ cancel: function () { alert("canceled"); } });  
and  
$kendoGrid = $("#grdTest").data("kendoGrid");  
$kendoGrid.options.cancel = function () {  
                    alert('Canceled');  
                };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$kendoGrid.unbind("cancel");
$kendoGrid.bind("cancel", gridCancel);